# If satement in one line with 2 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can you put this if satement in a single line?

```
if long_old != long_new:
      long = 'yes'
      counter_changes +=1
```

I've tried something like this:

```
long, counter_changes = ('yes',counter_changes +=1) if long_old != long_new
```

Syntax error...

Comment: Do you have a shortage of lines or something…?

Comment: it makes it more readable. I have 14 similiar statements.

Comment: Except when it doesn’t. Sounds like you might need some code refactoring to cut down on the repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```py
if long_old != long_new: long = 'yes'; counter_changes += 1
```

By putting a semicolon between the two statements, python lets you put them on one line. (However, this isn't recommended.)

You could also do:

```py
long, counter_changes = ("yes", counter_changes + 1) if long_old != new_old else (long, counter_changes)
```

Which sets `long` and `counter_changes` to `"yes"` and `counter_changes + 1` if the condition is true, but otherwise sets them to their previous values.

However, if long doesn't exist, you could just set it to another default value, such as an empty string:

```py
long, counter_changes = ("yes", counter_changes + 1) if long_old != new_old else ("", counter_changes)
```